# New tag for Oracle Database Appliance?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I have recently created a couple of questions related to the Oracle Database Appliance, and think it would be nice with a related tag.

I don't yet have enough reputation to create new tags, but perhaps someone who does will consider adding something like "ODA"?

I suppose a tag for Exadata couldn't hurt, either :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just tagged both of your questions with [oracle-database-appliance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-database-appliance).

Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thank you very much, both for the tags and the welcome!